# node js/mysql send json to server

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I am working a webpage using node js, node js express, mysql, html and javascript.
Right now I am trying to send Json data to the server. I can succesfully get data from my database, but I am having problems to send it as Json. This is the code I have.

```
app.get('/server/ordenes', function(req, res) { 
    console.log("SELECT * from orden"); 

    client.connect();
    var query = client.query("SELECT * from orden");

    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
    });
    query.on("end", function (result) {
        var response = {"orders" : result.rows};
        client.end();
        res.json(response);
    });
 });
```

but I am getting that rows is undefined.

I also tried this code:

```
 var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM orden ';

         client.query(queryString, function(err, row, result) {
         if (err) throw err;
         for (var i in row) {
             console.log(i);
             console.log('orders', row[i]);

             res.json(test);

         }

         client.end();

         });
```

but I cannot access the Json data from my app.js I think is because of the way it is displaying it.
This is my app.js code

```
function getOrders(){ 
    alert("entro");
    $.ajax({ 
        url : "http://192.XXX.X.XXX:8020/server/ordenes/", 
        contentType: "application/json", 
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
            var orderList = data.orders; 
            var len = orderList.length; 
            var list = document.getElementById("orders-list");          
            list.empty(); 
            var orderVal; 
            for (var i=0; i < len; ++i){ 
                orderVal = orderList[i];
                alert(orderVal.name);
                list.append("<p>Name: " + orderVal.name + "</p>"); 
            }    
            list.listview("refresh");    
        }, 
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
            console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus); 
            alert("Data not found!"); 
        } 
    }); 
 }
```

I go to the success but I cannot even display the orderList length